# Continusly run the Bash script on the Ubuntu Server as Process

Tags: command-line, server, bash, scripts, ssh

I Have a SCP upload script which uploads the files on the remote host. I am trying to run this script as background process so it can be even work when I am not logged into session.

I am trying to use `nohup` it doesn't work properly as soon as I close the session the files stops uploading to the remote server but I can still see that the script process is still running in back ground but no files are being uploaded.

I use this Command : `nohup sh /path_to_Script/script.sh`

and as well make sure that there is only **one script or process running and there is no duplication of same running script.**

please help.

Comment: I don't see any error messages posted, so I can only guess...try changing RemoveIPC to no in /etc/systemd/logind.conf

Comment: I don’t see the error as well. As I mentioned that file doesn’t upload but the script process still works after using sh with nohup command.